# Access to templates folder for non-admin users

Tags: security

I would like to give access to a user to a particular set of templates for editing, but I can't seem to do this.

The user is not an admin, and no matter what I do I can't seem to have him see the templates folder.  I've given him full rights to `\sitecore\templates`, given him multiple Sitecore roles including the developer.

The user isn't in the Sitecore domain, but other than that they don't have any rights that would be conflicting as far as I can see.  Are folders like `\Templates`, `\System`, etc. just not available unless you are an Admin user no matter what rights are granted?

Comment: just check whether you enabled "Entire tree" and "Hidden items" under "View" tab.?

Comment: That was it, thanks!